# Thread safe read of a class member vector without copying

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

Suppose I have a class:

```
class A
{
   private:
   std::vector<MyObject> history;
   std::mutex historyLock;
}
```

There are multiple threads initialized by that class which acquire the mutex and write to the history vector. Suppose then I have another class where I want to read that list:

```
class B
{
   public:
   B(A instanceA) 
   {
      // I want to read the list here in a thread safe way
   }
}
```

My intuition tells me to expose a method in `class A` called `GetHistory()`, which would lock the mutex, copy the list and return the copy.

Is there a way to read the list in class B without incurring the cost of a copy operation?

Comment: Why a second class?

Comment: @MichaelSurette class A might be a driver of some kind, class B might be an optional GUI for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this sort of problem.  One way is to use a more sophisticated structure to store your history, like an immutable vector.  (An immutable vector trades iteration performance for cheap copies.)  But using just standard C++, I think the easiest way is to add a traversal member function template to class A that accepts a callback:

```
template <class F> void TraverseHistory(F&& callback)
{
  std::lock_guard guard{ historyMutex };
  for (auto const& item : history)
  {
    callback(item);
  }
}
```

You can also use `std::function` if you prefer to avoid a function template:

```
void TraverseHistory(std::function<void(MyObject const&)> const& callback);
```

Yet another option is to pass a reference to the entire vector to your callback.  With that approach, the function template would look something like this:

```
template <class F> void ReadHistory(F&& callback)
{
  std::lock_guard guard{ historyMutex };
  callback(std::as_const(history));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it's a possible solution in my use-case. However, what if I want to do something like search it? Or iterate backwards? I would be forced to make a similar function for each operation to that vector. If this was an API for other users, I would be forcing the user to iterate through the structure in a certain way. Is there a way I can have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: I mean to say, yes this works but forces me to implement a whole bunch of operations on the vector, which may only be useful in a limited number of usecases. I can't foresee what operations a user of the API might want to perform on that vector, so by forcing them to use it like this, I limit their ability to work with the vector nicely. For instance, suppose the history vector has 2GB of data, and the user (class B) wants to search it using their own special type of search algorithm. They cannot perform this without copying in this solution

Comment: That doesn't strike me as entirely realistic.  Nevertheless, you don't have to pass a single element at a time.  I've shown it that way since it's generally the simplest approach.  But you can also pass a reference to the entire vector.

Comment: Passing a reference to the vector should work with the callback, thanks!